How To unique IDs with Hibernate in a distributed system
So I have a user entity in a Postgres Amazon Aurora DB & multiple pods of the same user service that inserts newly registered ones to the db
How would I handle the creation of unique user IDs? Could I just roll with the default ID generation in hibernate or doesn’t this work, because it isn’t global enough? & if not how would I solve this issue & would it still be possible to generate the IDs as longs?
& what would happen if my aurora db would be distributed in multiple regions? Would Hibernate be able to create a unique long for each user?

You can use uuid type for the id and gen_random_uuid() to generate it.

So the only possibility would be through UUIDs?

@Nikita it's the cleanest, safest, simplest and most scalable way.

A Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) is made to be unique. By far the best solution. Advice: Use version 7 if possible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_7_(timestamp,_counter_and_random)
